# Reducing subset sum to even subset sum

Tags: reductions, np-hard, subset-sum

I'm trying to learn reduction. I have this problem called "even subset sum" that's very similar to subset sum. It's the same problem as as subset sum except that the only numbers allowed are *even positive* integers. I'm trying to show this problem is NP-hard by reducing the problem subset sum to it but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Please state your problem, "even subset sum" in its full detail, assuming there is no prior knowledge of subset sum at all.

Comment: Given a set S of even positive integers and an integer k, is there a subset of S  whose sum equals k?

Comment: It should be noted that the sets do not contain duplicate integers in both problems.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: suppose that we are able to solve your problem efficiently. Then what if we take an arbitrary subset sum problem and multiply all elements by $2$, as well as the target?